# Why does my SQL give me results when criteria parameters are not being met

Tags: php, sql

I have the following SQL query that is executed by a PHP script. The issue is even when the `$nameValue` parameter is not met it still returns values. How can this be fixed? I specifically say:

```
WHERE ((driver_name = '$nameValue') AND
        status = 'FEDEX' or status = 'UPS')
```

The `AND` should return only when both are met but it still shows all where status is `FEDEX` or `UPS`

```
$sql =  "SELECT customer,
       sum( status = 'FEDEX' ) as PickedUpNUM,
       sum( status = 'UPS' ) as DeliveryNUM
        from Equipment
        WHERE ((driver_name = '$nameValue') AND
        status = 'FEDEX' or status = 'UPS')
        group by customer
        Order by DeliveryNUM DESC";
```

Comment: `AND status = 'FEDEX' or status = 'UPS'` You're mixing and/or clauses. Use parenthesis to block off the ones that should go together, such as `driver_name = '$nameValue' AND (status = 'FEDEX' or status = 'UPS')`

Comment: Try to change parenthesis : `WHERE driver_name = '$nameValue' AND (status = 'FEDEX' or status = 'UPS')`

Answer (score 1):

wrong () position

```
$sql =  "SELECT customer,
          sum( status = 'FEDEX' ) as PickedUpNUM,
          sum( status = 'UPS' ) as DeliveryNUM
          from Equipment
          WHERE driver_name = '$nameValue' AND
          (status = 'FEDEX' or status = 'UPS')
        group by customer
        Order by DeliveryNUM DESC";
```

Answer (score 0):

To get your query to return the results that you require you need to make a couple of changes

```
$sql =  "SELECT customer,
          sum( IF(status = 'FEDEX', 1, 0 ) as PickedUpNUM,
          sum( IF(status = 'UPS', 1, 0 ) as DeliveryNUM
          from Equipment
          WHERE driver_name = '$nameValue' AND
          (status = 'FEDEX' or status = 'UPS')
        group by customer
        Order by DeliveryNUM DESC";
```